# How do you center a picture and left align text that is touching said picture? HTML5

Tags: css, html

This book is so confusing... I'm back with yet another question.

The book shows a picture of the chapters final look, and obviously I'm having problems with it.

**Issue 1:** I need to center a picture (I know how to do this) but what I don't know is how to left align a sentence after the picture. By after, I mean it would look like this picture:
[image]

But the centered text needs to be left aligned to the image, and when it reaches the end of the page, it starts the text under the picture instead of centered.

I'm pretty sure this has something to do with my wrapper, but I'm not 100% sure on what it is.

CSS file that controls most of the visual things below:

```
header {
  background-color: #ccaa66;
  color: #000000;
  text-align: center;
}

h1 {
  line-height: 200%;
}

body {
  background-color: #ffffaa;
  color: #330000;
  font-family: Verdana;
  background: url(background.gif);
  padding: 25px;
}

nav {
  text-align: center;
}

footer {
  background-color: #ccaa66;
  color: #000000;
  font-size: 0.60em;
  font-style: italic;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 5px;
}

#wrapper {
  background-color: #ffffaa;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  width: 80%;
  min-width: 700px;
  max-width: 1024px;
}

h2 {
  background-color: #ccaa66;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
}

.details {
  padding-left: 20%;
  padding-right: 20%;
}

img {
  border: 0px solid;
}
```

Now, the html page I'm loading that is having issues, is a `"music"` page, and since I can't really upload all of the necessary items you would need to fully construct the page, I'm going to have to go by word of wise.

The music.html page is coded like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="javajam.css">

<header>
  <title> JavaJam Coffee House Music</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <h1><img src="javalogo.gif" alt="JavaJam Coffee House Logo" height="119" width="619"></h1>
</header>

<nav>
  <a href="index.html">Home</a> &nbsp;
  <a href="menu.html">Menu</a> &nbsp;
  <a href="music.html">Music</a> &nbsp;
  <a href="jobs.html">Jobs</a>
</nav>

<body>
  <div id="wrapper">
    <p> The first Friday night each month at JavaJam is a special night. Join us from 8pm to 11pm for some music you won't want to miss! </p>
    <h2> January </h2>
    <p align="center"><img src="melaniethumb.jpg" alt="Melanie Morris">Melanie Morris entertains with her melodic folk style. <br> Check out the Podcast! CDs are now available.</p>
    <h2> February </h2>
    <p align="center"><img src="gregthumb.jpg" alt="Tahoe Greg">Tahoe Greg's back from his tour. New songs. New stories. CD's now available. </p>
  </div>
</body>

<footer>
  <em>Copyright &copy 2014 JavaJam Coffee House</em> <br>
  <a href="mailto:Johnathon@Olivas.com">Johnathon@Olivas.com</a>
</footer>

</html>
```

What I'm really looking for is just a way to make the picture show up have the text follow the bottom right of the picture, and when it reaches the `"end"` of the page, it wraps back and stars under the picture instead of being center aligned. Namely where that `<br>` is, would be nice to have the text star back under the picture again.

If you need more info I'll try my best to provide it, but as I said earlier, I'm unable to give the actual pictures in the assignment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found some errors in the markup of the Web page.

This is the correction of your HTML.

I added a div tag with content class.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <title> JavaJam Coffee House Music</title>
</head>

<body>
    <header>
        <h1><img src="javalogo.gif" alt="JavaJam Coffee House Logo" height="119" width="619"></h1>
    </header>

    <nav>
        <a href="index.html">Home</a> &nbsp;
        <a href="menu.html">Menu</a> &nbsp;
        <a href="music.html">Music</a> &nbsp;
        <a href="jobs.html">Jobs</a>
    </nav>

    <div id="wrapper">
        <p>
            The first Friday night each month at JavaJam is a special night. Join us from
            8pm to 11pm for some music you won't want to miss!
        </p>
        <h2> January </h2>
        <div class="content">
            <p><img src="melaniethumb.jpg" alt="Melanie Morris">Melanie Morris entertains with her melodic folk style. <br> Check out the Podcast! CDs are now available.</p>
        </div>
        <h2> February </h2>
        <div class="content">
            <p><img src="gregthumb.jpg" alt="Tahoe Greg">Tahoe Greg's back from his tour. New songs. New stories. CD's now available. </p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <footer>
        <em>Copyright &copy; 2014 JavaJam Coffee House</em> <br>
        <a href="mailto:Johnathon@Olivas.com">Johnathon@Olivas.com</a>
    </footer>
</body>
</html>
```

I've added a css class «.content» to center the content.

```
header {
    background-color: #ccaa66;
    color: #000000;
    text-align: center;
}

h1 {
    line-height: 200%;
}

body {
    background-color: #ffffaa;
    color: #330000;
    font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;
    background: url(background.gif);
    padding: 25px;
}

nav {
    text-align: center;
}

footer {
    background-color: #ccaa66;
    color: #000000;
    font-size: 0.60em;
    font-style: italic;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 5px;
}

#wrapper {
    background-color: #ffffaa;
    color: inherit;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    width: 80%;
    min-width: 700px;
    max-width: 1024px;
}

h2 {
    background-color: #ccaa66;
    color: inherit;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
}

.details {
    padding-left: 20%;
    padding-right: 20%;
}

img {
    border: 0px solid;
}

.content {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 600px;
}
```

I hope this helps you.

Comment: Yes! thank you! :D book didn't really say what the margin was actually for, and somehow I got in the midset that border was how you fixed it lol. Thank you tho! :)

Answer (score 0):

This should help you out. http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wKKLjG. the image is marked as `display:inline-block` and `float:left`. Refer more on [css](/questions/tagged/css)float property.  http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_float.asp.